# How to assign a value to a textbox by onclick button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am generating passwords automatically by using php. I stored the generated password in a variable. Here i have assign those generated passwords to a text box by using ONCLICK property on button(button name is "Generate Password"). But i am not getting required output(password must be visible in textbox by clicking that button). Here i have attached respective code. Can anyone tell  what i had done wrong??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>create_profile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="create_profile.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function getPassword(){
        document.getElementById("password").value="<?php

    // Characters to use for the password
    $str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    // Desired length of the password
    $pwlen = 8;

    // Length of the string to take characters from
    $len = strlen($str);

    // RANDOM.ORG - We are pulling our list of random numbers as a
    // single request, instead of iterating over each character individually
    $uri = "http://www.random.org/integers/?";
    $random = file_get_contents(
        $uri ."num=$pwlen&min=0&max=".($len-1)."&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"
    );
    $indexes = explode("\n", $random);
    array_pop($indexes);

    // We now have an array of random indexes which we will use to build our password
    $pw = '';
    foreach ($indexes as $int){
        $pw .= substr($str, $int, 1);

    }
```

echo $pw;

?>";
            }

```
    </script>
```

```
    <h1> Create Profile </h1>

    <label for="name">name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="30" /><br />

    <label for="user_id">user id:</label><br />
    <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" size="30" /><br />

    <label for="email">Your Email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="60" /><br />




    <label for="password">password:</label><br />
    <input id="password" name="password" size = "10" /> <br/>
    <button onclick="getpassword();" >Generate Password</button>
```

Comment: You're going to have to try it for yourself before you'll find help on stackoverflow. Stackoverflow members help those who help themselves, no handouts here ;)

Comment: I had already tried it by myself. I had written code for generating passwords in php. But i am not getting any ideas to display that variable (password) in a text field by clicking a button.

Comment: There appears to be a direct contradiction in your last statement. First, you say "I had already tried it by myself". Next you say "But I am not getting idea to...." Please do tell - how exactly does one try something oneself without even having an idea of what to do(try)? Thinking about such a question does *not* constitute trying to solve it. Google brought you here, google will take you to the answer. It's programming 101 - break down the problem into manageable chunks before solving each of them (divide-and-conquer). (1) respond to btn click (2) set value of an input element. Combine 1 & 2

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions friend. I did all what i can do here, and i have attached respective code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correction of your suggestion

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ab</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $pw="hello"; ?>
// You've written here getPassword()
function getpassword(){
document.getElementById("password").value="<?php echo $pw; ?>";
}

</script>
</head>
<label for="password"> password: </label><br />


<input id="password" name="password" size = "10" />                  
<!-- there is no need for a semicolon here -->
<button onclick="getpassword()" >Generate Password</button>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

without php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ab</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

// You've written here getPassword()
function getpassword(){
document.getElementById("password").value="hello";
}

</script>
</head>
<label for="password"> password: </label><br />


<input id="password" name="password" size = "10" />                  
<!-- there is no need for a semicolon here -->
<button onclick="getpassword()" >Generate Password</button>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have attached code to my question. Could you tell me what i have made wrong ?

Comment: @user2798220 I've posted the correction. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Wait a moment I will test it myself.

Comment: @user2798220 For me, they work both. You can try now the version without php. When it works then it's a problem with your php configuration.

Comment: Its working without php., my php is all set., because other php code is working well for me...

Comment: @user2798220 Can you show you code for the php password generation?

Answer (score 0):

first-time learn javascript and  jquery(it is javascript library) :)
if you use jquery

```
<button onclick="function(){ $.get('/url/',function(dataReturnFromServer){alert(dataReturnFromServer);})}"></button>
```